# how to set EndDate's minDate to what value is in StartDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Say you have two `datepicker`.

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
  mindDate: 0
});

$("#EndDate").datepicker({
  minDate: // how to set here the StartDate's value?
});
```

How can I set the `minDate` of `$("#EndDate")` to whatever value is in `$("#StartDate")`?

What I have tried so far is,

```
$("#EndDate").datepicker({
  beforeShow: function() {
    $(this).datepicker('minDate', $("#StartDate").val(); // Still not getting the value from #StartDate
  }
});
```

Still the `minDate` is not taking into effect. What should I do to make it right? Any thought? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sample provided by jQuery! With `OnClose` :

```
$(function() {
    $("#StartDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $("#EndDate").datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });

    $("#EndDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

See here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range